# A better way for transformation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have something as

[image]

obtained by running the script

```
declare @t table(id int identity, bucket varchar(200), startinventory int, nocontact int)

INSERT INTO @t  
SELECT 'bucket1',1234,72500 UNION ALL  
SELECT 'bucket2',6784,60500 UNION ALL  
SELECT 'bucket3',678,52000 UNION ALL  
SELECT 'bucket4',234,45000 

select * from @t
```

Looking for a transformation whose output will be

[image]

The present script which does the transformation is presented below

```
select 'startinventory'  as Activities,
    bucket1=(select startinventory from @t where id=1),
    bucket2=(select startinventory from @t where id=2), 
    bucket3=(select startinventory from @t where id=3),
    bucket4=(select startinventory from @t where id=4) union all
select 'nocontact', 
    (select nocontact from @t where id=1),
    (select nocontact from @t where id=2), 
    (select nocontact from @t where id=3),
    (select nocontact from @t where id=4)
```

Is there a better way to write the script?

Comment: a dynamic query using pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big assumption that you only have a fixed 4 buckets, but if so this will do it (with sample data provided).

```
declare @bucket table(id int, bucket varchar(10), startinventory int, nocontact int)
insert @bucket values (1,'bucket1',1234,72500),(2,'bucket2',6784,60500),(3,'bucket3',678,52000),(4,'bucket4',234,45000)

select a as Activity,
    sum(case when id=1 then case when a='startinventory' then startinventory else NoContact end else 0 end) as bucket1,
    sum(case when id=2 then case when a='startinventory' then startinventory else NoContact end else 0 end) as bucket2,
    sum(case when id=3 then case when a='startinventory' then startinventory else NoContact end else 0 end) as bucket3,
    sum(case when id=4 then case when a='startinventory' then startinventory else NoContact end else 0 end) as bucket4
from (values ('startinventory'),('nocontact')) t(a)
cross join @bucket b
group by a
```